Hololens 1 receiving but not sending data over NetMQ publisher websocket (TCP connection), but no error messages
I'm trying to make a Hololens (gen 1) send some data over a publisher websocket to a PC (which receives the data using a python script). When testing in Unity, everything works fine. When testing with the Hololens, however, I'm not receiving any data on the PC. I also have a subscriber socket in the app receiving data from a python script, and that works perfectly fine.
The script I'm using is nearly identical to the Listener script in this repository: https://github.com/gench23/unity-zeromq-client/blob/master/Assets/Scripts/PubSub/Listener.cs but with a publisher socket that sends string data. The script behaviour is regulated by a script nearly identical to: https://github.com/gench23/unity-zeromq-client/blob/master/Assets/Scripts/PubSub/Client.cs.
In the Unity project settings, I have InternetClient, InternetClientServer and PrivateNetworkClientServer enabled. On the Hololens, I'm publishing with a TCP connection to host:[Hololens IP], port:[chosen port]. On the PC, I'm subscribing to the same host and port. The port I'm using is allowed through the Firewall. As far as I can tell in debug mode, I'm not getting any errors related to setting up the websocket in Hololens. My best guess is that the Hololens itself has a firewall that's blocking the signal? Are there any ways to fix that so the signal gets through to the PC?
(Or if all else fails, any tips for alternative methods to send data to a PC?)

Note: I've tried disabling the firewall on the PC entirely, it did not help
